# Saving a word document results in "Command failed"

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I've been trying to save a word document based on this code:

```
Private Sub CreateWordDoc()

        Dim wa As Word.Application
        Dim wd As Word.Document
        Dim wp As Word.Paragraph

        wa = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wa.Visible = False

        wd = wa.Documents.Add
        wp = wd.Content.Paragraphs.Add

        wp.Range.Text = rtxtRecipeContents.Text

        wd.SaveAs(Application.StartupPath & "\" & RecipeName & ".docx")
        wa.Quit()

    End Sub
```

However, an error occurs highlighting "wd.SaveAs(Application.StartupPath & "\" & RecipeName & ".docx")" saying that "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Command failed'"

The document never saves. However, when changing the wd.SaveAs path to something simple on my C: drive, it works perfectly fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciateted. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to save a document to the file path your code should be using as an end-user, in Word? Is it possible your .NET application doesn't have the necessary permission to save to `Application.StartupPath`? I do find using this location rather odd...

Answer (score 1):

After wasting a few hours, trying all sorts of recipes from making document visible/invible to playing with DCOM Config utility, it turned out that I was getting "command failed" for Save command because another part of my code was handling `DocumentBeforeSave` event and cancelling save operation by setting `ref Cancel` parameter to `true`.

Putting it here as a note for myself. Hope this helps someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not apparent from your code where 'RecipeName' comes from. In VBA, you might use code like:

```
Private Sub CreateWordDoc(RecipeName As String, RecipeContents As String)
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
With wdApp
  .Visible = False
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add(Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    .Range.Text = RecipeContents
    .SaveAs2 FileName:=Application.StartupPath & "\" & RecipeName & ".docx", _
      Fileformat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
    .Close False
  End With
  .Quit
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

passing both RecipeName and RecipeContents (equivalent to your rtxtRecipeContents.Text) to the sub. For example:

Call CreateWordDoc(rtxtRecipeName.Text, rtxtRecipeContents.Text)

As for the Save problem itself, you might not have permission to write to the application's folder. Try replacing:

Application.StartupPath & "\"

with, for example:

"C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Documents\"

or:

wdApp.Options.DefaultFilePath (wdDocumentsPath) & "\"